# If you cast Darkness using sorcery points as a Shadow Magic sorcerer, do you need material components?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, sorcerer, spell-components

Shadow Magic sorcerers at 3rd level gain the spell Darkness, which doesn't count against their spells known. In addition, they can cast it by expending 2 sorcery points.

Can you circumvent the need for material components by using sorcery points?

I'm assuming you do need the components, as sorcery points seem to function like auxiliary spell slots.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Yes

The [Shadow Magic sorcerer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#ShadowMagic)'s [Eyes of the Dark](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#EyesoftheDark-750) feature makes no special mention of components, therefore they must be provided as normal.

> [...] [Y]ou learn the *darkness* spell, which doesn't count against your number of sorcerer spells known. In addition, you can cast it by spending 2 sorcery points or by expending a spell slot. If you cast it with sorcery points, you can see through the darkness created by the spell.
>
> --- *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, p. 51

As *darkness* is a sorcerer spell you are eligible to use use your arcane focus for the casting, assuming you use one. No need to carry around bat fur and pitch, unless you like doing that, which as a Shadow Sorcerer you well might.

---

As a comparison, Shadow Monks get at 6th level the ability to cast *darkness* using 2 ki points, but don't need to provide material components. They don't get to use spell slots though for obvious reasons.

> As an action, you can spend 2 ki points to cast *darkness*,
>   *darkvision*, *pass without trace*, or *silence*, without
>   providing material components.
>
> --- *Player's Handbook*, p. 80